# Is there a way to debug VC++ compiled applications using Eclipse/WinDbg?

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, debugging, windbg

I'm currently using Eclipse as my main editor, and source browser for our C/C++ project. The only problem is, I have to switch to Visual C++ everytime I have to debug or trace. Is there a way to have Eclipse use the WinDbg tool to debug Windows native applications? I tried searching on the web but all the forum posts seem to trail off to nowhere around 2007/2008.

Comment: Why not just use windbg itself to debug? You can do full source level debugging within windbg.

Comment: I wanted to use eclipse's built in browser. As I mentioned in the question, the issue was I didn't want to go in and out of Eclipse. I already use VC++ right now for debugging native Windows Apps.

Comment: The question could be simplified as "is mingw gdb possible to debug vc++ compiled application?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. Because you will not have access to the Win Debug Symbols and libraries within the Eclipse runtime. However you could start building this as an Eclipse plugin for VS users.

Comment: thanks. the project sounds interesting, I'll try to find time for this.